# How dangerous is it to pass around socket.io socket id?

Tags: node.js, security, express, websocket, socket.io

So I have a form that will allow someone to enter the id of a live socket.io socket. On submit, the server will take that id and broadcast a message using it.

So on the server is essentially:

```
app.post '/', (req, res) ->
  socket_id = req.body.socket_id
  io.to(socket_id).emit('message', {hello: "world"})
  res.redirect '/'
```

This also obviously means that I am exposing the id in plaintext somewhere.

How would this affect the overall security of the application? Would it be possible for someone to use this id to attack my application?

Comment: This probably isn't a good idea, especially if you can emit something that can change backend state. But if you're doing it via SSL then you're a little better off.